# How to execute python script on button click in Power BI?

Tags: python, powerbi-desktop

I have added button in Power BI. But didn't get which action should I use to button so that python script will run by clicking action.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is no support yet for Python to be able to communicate directly with the PowerBI context. As per this [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Python-script-activated-on-Button/td-p/945068), python and other visuals can only interact with the outer DOM for processing.